# CSS3 border-image Repeat Not working in Chrome 56

Tags: css, google-chrome, border, border-image

I have an element set with a border image that is not uniform and needs to repeat on edges. Works perfectly in all browsers except Chrome 56.0.2924.76 but fine in newer and older versions of chrome.

In the version that doesn't work, it does repeat on the edges but not where the slices are defined.

[image]

(Sorry, I had to blur some content, client site is not live yet)

https://jsfiddle.net/np1kmsut/1/

```css
.main-content {
  background: url('../images/texture-bg-light.jpg');
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 69px 74px 24px 74px;
  -moz-border-image: url(http://10poundgorilla.com/-temp/sign-border-mobile.jpg) 69 74 24 74 repeat;
  -webkit-border-image: url(http://10poundgorilla.com/-temp/sign-border-mobile.jpg) 69 74 24 74 repeat; 
  -o-border-image: url(http://10poundgorilla.com/-temp/sign-border-mobile.jpg) 69 74 24 74 repeat; 
  border-image: url(http://10poundgorilla.com/-temp/sign-border-mobile.jpg) 69 74 24 74 repeat;

  margin: 0 2rem 256px 2rem;
  padding: 3.3rem 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
<h1>Testing</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the reason of not using the latest version of Chrome (57.0.2987.133)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [quick-n-dirty solution](https://jsfiddle.net/np1kmsut/2/) you may have already tried would be setting the `border-image-repeat` property to `stretch`. Of course it looks...stretched.

Otherwise, the problem has to do with your image's dimensions and their interplay with the border-image slices. Use a square image (I used 250px x 250px) and you should be all set.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/np1kmsut/3/)

I hope this helps!

Comment: I did see before that stretch fixed the issue but for my purposes I needed it to repeat but adjusting the image to a square fixed the problem. Very odd that it was only an issue in that one version of Chrome.